# CAN updater with Raspberry for NXP microcontroller (MKE06Z64VLH4)

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, can-bus, nxp-microcontroller

we have system which runs on NXP KE06 chip (MKE06Z64VLH4). It's stationary system, which was developed from primary company, which is not interested in quick bug fixing (there is a lot of bugs) and further development.
Now we have a job to solve a problem, without primary company. We have right now 200 products all over the country. If we want to update mentioned NXP chip, we need to travel to destination, take machine apart,
make and update for NXP chip over SWD (.HEX file) manualy and assemble each machine together again.

We have our controlling system on Raspberry, which is running Raspbian and we have RS-485 half-duplex connection between Raspberry and NXP chip. (which connection continues to CAN --> NXP chip)
We want to solve this problem with software and with current hardware. (With changing all current hardware, with new hardware solution, solves the problem)

Question:
Is possible to make an "remote" updater/flasher with .HEX file, and with current hardware?
FACTS: - we can't ask company for source code
- we have current .HEX file
- we don't want to replace all hardware (200+ pieces)
- we don't know the source code

Answer (score 2):

> Is possible to make an "remote" updater/flasher with .HEX file, and with current hardware?

No, because for that to be an option, the MCU must already have a bootloader alternative inside itself.

NXP hates their customers, so they block anyone from reading the manual without logging in... I managed to eventually get it. There is no mentioning of on-chip bootloader support save for SWD. The part can only be programmed by SWD or by a custom bootloader that you'd have to develop.

UART-based bootloaders are not uncommon - you could write one yourself using either UART/RS-485 or CAN, but then you'd have to update the firmware to download the bootloader, so it isn't helpful in this case.

Summary: you need something with SWD on-site or it can't be done.

Also please note that these MCUs typically have anti-copycat protection enabled, preventing you from reading anything out of it. Depending on how they were programmed, this could be present and then the only thing you can do is to erase and flash the whole program.